# Scheduled tasks not running on time in Spring

Tags: spring, cron

I use @Schedule to have the system run tasks at different time.  But recently, I found that some of the tasks are being postponed.  For example, there is one task which should run on 5:00 every morning, now runs sometimes in the noon or even later in the afternoon.  Any ideas?  Thanks.

Scheduler service:

```
@Service
public class DailyReminderTasks extends AbstractTask {

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(DailyReminderTasks.class);

private SendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 5  * * ?")
// run at 5:00 am every day
public void sendAuditReponseReminderLetter() {      
    try {
        sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce.sendAuditReponseReminder();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("failed to send reminder: ", ex);
    }
}

public SendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce getSendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce() {
    return sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce;
}

@Autowired(required = true)
public void setSendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce(
        SendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce) {
    this.sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce = sendAuditReminderNotificationSerivce;
}
```

Comment: Can your task take longer than 24h to run? Do you have many other `@Scheduled` annotations in your code? Without that information, hard to say. Also I believe this has nothing to do with `quartz-scheduler` unless you have extra configuration.

Comment: I don't have task running longer than 24 hours.  And I do have many @Scheduled annotations to schedule different task at different time.  I don't have extra configuration for quartz-scheduler.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the information available here, the most likely explanation is that the background thread pool handling task scheduling does not keep up and thus between the time the task is put on the queue and the time it is executed, many hours can pass.

Comment: Any solutions?  Thanks.